# rule of thumb for estimating size of keys_zone for nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy, but trying to figure out how large I should set the 'keys_zone' attribute on the 'proxy_cache_path' directive.  The only advice on determining that size that I have found is http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2053000

However this does not sound right to me as 'max_size / (average file size)' seems like way overkill.

Isn't keys_zone just the metadata for the cached file on disk? therefore, the size of a given entry should be really small. Is there any way to do a 'get' on an entry in the zone so I can see how much space a given entry is taking up?

Answer (score 2):

Per http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

Zone size should be set proportional to number of pages to cache. The size of the metadata for one page (file) depends on the OS; currently it is 64 bytes for FreeBSD/i386, and 128 bytes for FreeBSD/amd64.